# Adding retention period to Loki config file returns "field retention not found in type config.plain. Use `-config.expand-env=true`"

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I have downloaded the Loki config file from here: wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grafana/loki/v2.8.0/cmd/loki/loki-local-config.yaml -O loki-config.yaml

After that I created the docker image. And then when I run this command everything works perfect: docker run --name loki -v :/mnt/config -p 3100:3100 grafana/loki:2.8.0 --config.file=/mnt/config/loki-config.yaml

But the problem is when I try to add retention in the Loki config file, I get the following error:
**failed parsing config: /mnt/config/loki-config.yaml: yaml: unmarshal errors:
line 35: field retention not found in type config.plain. Use `-config.expand-env=true` flag if you want to expand environment variables in your config file**

I have tried a lot of ways, but still nothing is working and I am stuck. Here is my config file:

```
auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100
  grpc_listen_port: 9096

common:
  instance_addr: 127.0.0.1
  path_prefix: /tmp/loki
  storage:
    filesystem:
      chunks_directory: /tmp/loki/chunks
      rules_directory: /tmp/loki/rules
  replication_factor: 1
  ring:
    kvstore:
      store: inmemory

query_range:
  results_cache:
    cache:
      embedded_cache:
        enabled: true
        max_size_mb: 100

schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2022-01-01
      store: boltdb-shipper
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 24h
      retention:
        enabled: true
        period: 30d

ruler:
  alertmanager_url: http://localhost:9093
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such setting as retention when looking at https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/configuration/. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish by setting retention so I don't know if there are any matching configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct configuration is

```
table_manager:
  retention_deletes_enabled: true # true so that storage is limited
  retention_period: 2160h #3 months
```

Credits to [1](https://github.com/caosbinario/observability/blob/main/02-monitoreo-logs/loki-config.yml) based on [2](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/configure/#table_manager)